# Cannot connect Java to MySQL database even after having jar file

Tags: java, mysql, selenium, dbconnection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbManager {
    public static Connection conn = null; // mysql
    public static void setMysqlDbConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase");
            System.out.println("test1");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase", "root", "Password");
            System.out.println("test2");
            if (!conn.isClosed())
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL server");

            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
     }
}
```

Output is:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase
test1
Cannot connect to database server
```

The connection is not working as expected. I have confirmed that the jar installed and connection is working with the username and password on Terminal. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace()`  in exception block. then add stacktrace error in your question

Comment: `setMysqlDbConnection` should be `getMysqlDbConnection`  or setter with values and print the stack trace as mentionned in the comment above.

Comment: @Avarma Could you mention the name and version of mysql connector jar. Since you havn't mentioned about what the error the program is causing by printing the stacktrace, its hard to debug. I'm able to connect with my database by your code.

Comment: Thanks, @GolamMazidsajib for making me remember about stack trace. I totally forgot to use it. The issue got fixed after adding the timezone. The new code is 

"conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "My Password");"

Thanks, HarryCoder and Vishnu Prabhakar for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned `serverTimezone` explicitly in the code to fix the issue.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "MyPassword");
```